# Html sound refuses to loop

Tags: html, loops, audio

I'm basically trying to loop a sound on my webpage. But it doesn't work. The sound play once, and not forever, which I want to.

This is the code:

```
<embed src="static.ogg" width="32" height="32" loop="true"></embed>
```

I have no clue what is wrong with this line. But well, plays once, nothing more.

Also tried the audio tag, but the looping isn't that good in that (to my experience, but I'm a newbie), since I basically notice when a sound repeats itself.

Comment: The `audio` tag is the new way to go. What makes you think it will work better with `embed`?

Comment: not sure, thought embed was the new thing. but is there a way to make the audio loop more fluently? the audiofiles is fine when looping in like Audacity, so it's something else that makes it really noticable when it repeats. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends probably onthe browser.

Answer (score 0):

On one of my websites ([comic sans will rule](http://comicsanswillrule.github.io)) I have used this code:

```html
    <audio src="http://comicsanswillrule.github.io/ComicSans.mp3" controls autoplay loop>
```

I have put ComicSans.mp3 into the same folder as my index/home file.
I could also have used src="ComicSans.mp3"  or wherever the audio file is.

In summary, try:

Comment: You need to re-read the [Behavior guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), as signatures are not allowed